# Script Updating Connection Properties in exported flow/powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, flow, powerapp, connection

Question: Is it possible to update the connection properties of an exported flow/powerapps package via powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to update the connection properties of an exported flow/powerapps package via PowerShell script.

Comment: Figured as much. Thanks!

Comment: if the post helps you, you can mark it as answer.Thanks for your understanding